# Determining time-signatures by listening

Tags: time-signatures

I make a triange in the air (with sound of pine-app-le) for 3/4, and square (sounds like hop-scotch), but 6/8 hexagon is less accurate (no sound known), any ideas for it? 9/8 and other unsual ones are more challenging....

Comment: If this is about the shapes for beating time, triangle points are good for 3/4, 4/4 is usually the numbers 6,3,9,12 on a clock face, and 6/8 just down and up - 6 and 12.

Comment: I think it's hard to beat the classical conducting moves for 6/8: down left left right right up in little hops.